# How do I derive a trait for another trait?

Tags: rust, traits

I have a struct that holds a trait object member like this:

```
trait Contract {}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Foo {
    x: Box<dyn Contract>,
}
```

I want that struct to derive `Debug`, but the compiler doesn't like it:

```
error[E0277]: `Contract + 'static` doesn't implement `std::fmt::Debug`
 --> src/main.rs:5:5
  |
5 |     x: Box<Contract>,
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `Contract + 'static` cannot be formatted using `:?`; add `#[derive(Debug)]` or manually implement `std::fmt::Debug`
  |
  = help: the trait `std::fmt::Debug` is not implemented for `Contract + 'static`
  = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::fmt::Debug` for `std::boxed::Box<Contract + 'static>`
  = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::fmt::Debug` for `&std::boxed::Box<Contract + 'static>`
  = note: required for the cast to the object type `std::fmt::Debug`
```

I'm not really sure how to approach fixing this. I understand why the compiler can't implement `Debug` for the trait since it can't tell what types will implement it, but that same reason is what keeps me from implementing it manually for the trait (not even sure if that's even possible).

What would be a good approach to obtain the behaviour I want?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Traits can't use the `#[derive()]` attribute; you need to implement it manually:

```
trait Contract {}

impl std::fmt::Debug for dyn Contract {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter) -> std::fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "{}", "derp")
    }
}
```

Since trait objects lose information on the type ([type erasure](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/first-edition/trait-objects.html#dynamic-dispatch)) you could utilize the functions implemented by `Contract`, but you won't have access to the underlying types or their specific implementations of `Debug`.

If, however, you make `Contract` dependent on the `Debug` trait, ensuring that all its implementors must also implement `Debug`:

```
trait Contract: std::fmt::Debug {}
```

You will be able to `#[derive(Debug)]` for `foo` without having to implement `Debug` for `Contract` manually.

Comment: Fantastic, that's exactly the Rust syntax I was looking for. Thank you very much!

Answer (score -2):

As per Rust 2021, You can implement trait for another trait like this:

```rust
trait Contract: Debug {}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Foo {
    x: Box<Contract>,
}
```

Comment: This is already covered in the existing answer (and this is not new to Rust 2021).